# Answer etiquette on older questions

Tags: discussion, etiquette, old-questions

In relation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901049/how-do-i-connect-to-mysql-5-1-in-visual-studio-2010/2786413)

I came across this myself.  There were several answers saying "it doesn't work because its a bug" or "try this" (and it doesn't work.)

To be honest I just didn't believe that, and so found a solution.

What's the etiquette here?  Should I reply in the comments to each person "hey I found an answer, try this"? (since they will get a notification saying a new comment has been added)

Obviously I want the rep love!  But I understand it might come across as spam...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible the answers were correct at the time they were posted. Or perhaps, you *did* find a solution others overlooked.

I see no problem posting your answer and, further, adding comments to *any* post where you find factual errors. That is the purpose of comments. The wiki aspect of Stack Overflow is to continually update and improve existing answers as *well* as provide newer, updated answers.

Answer (score 4):

If an answer is wrong there is nothing wrong with pointing that out with a comment.