# Add a badge for "high return on investment"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

Some users get a huge load of reputation with little effort. Probably, that's mostly due to some weird voting effects, where a question is upvoted unreasonably high. Yet, it would still be interesting to see, which users would actually win a badge indicating that they have asked / answered few questions and still got a lot of reputation. An (extreme) example user:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1127571/honza-brabec

1 question, 1 answer, 1386 repuation! Maybe the badge would be awarded to those users that

- Have asked/answered at least 10 questions (to avoid weird effects, i.e. the above user shouldn't get this badge)
- Have gotten an average of 20 upvotes or +200 reputation (example) per question/answer

This would be a bit similar to the [legendary](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/146/legendary) badge, except that the measurement is less absolute.

Hmm... This might be a duplicate of this:
[New Badge Suggestion for high average scores on answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96050/new-badge-suggestion-for-high-average-scores-on-answers). In any case, it's related

Note: You may think that badges should *encourage* behaviour. But then again, there are already many badges that just award arbitrary things that a single user cannot influence:

- [tumbleweed](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed)
- [unsung hero](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero)
- [stellar question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/36/stellar-question)
- [tenacious](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/225/tenacious)

Comment: In other words, a "reverse Unsung Hero" badge?

Comment: what name u propose?

Comment: @Mystical: Yes, kinda.

Comment: [John Carmack says hello](http://superuser.com/users/131344/john-carmack). 1 answer, 1904 rep & counting. Also, unregistered user.

Comment: That user already got 10 badges, including 2 gold ones for that question. You want to add an 11th?

Comment: @Mat: That's why users eligible for a "high ROI" badge need to ask/answer at least 10 questions

Comment: possible duplicate of [New Badge Suggestion for high average scores on answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96050/new-badge-suggestion-for-high-average-scores-on-answers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't want to encourage this for several reasons:

1. often it's not the technical quality of the answer that results in the high votes but rather some meta-effect (funny answer, linked from reddit, correct timing, ...)
2. the answerer *already* gets plenty of rewards for such an answer
3. there is little one can do to *actively* pursue such a badge, except post and hope for luck

In my mind the main problem is #1: extremely high voted answers (or questions) are usually not rated highly because of their technical merit. For example, looking at my top answers, the majority of them are rather simple problems (with simple solutions). Only a few are actually somewhat complex and/or interesting.

Comment: All your 3 points also account for: [tumbleweed](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed), [unsung hero](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero), [stellar question](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/36/stellar-question), [tenacious](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/225/tenacious) etc... Note, your point #1 would justify removal of the existing [famous question](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/28/famous-question), [great question](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/22/great-question), and [great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/25/great-answer) badges

Comment: @LukasEder: that point could be used to argue for the removal of those badges, that is correct. But it doesn't change my argument in any way. Those badges don't bother me, so I don't argue against them. I just don't think that more badges in those direction are necessary.

Comment: OK, never mind then. I can see that this idea doesn't stand a chance

Comment: @LukasEder You are right that the reasons above also argue against "Stellar Question", "Great Answer", etc., but I don't think the same is true as much for "Tumbleweed" and "Unsung Hero" since the meta-effects mentioned matter more on the high end of popularity.